# FillNa is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following column of a dataframe:

```
    LC_REF
     2C16
     2C17
     2C18
      nan
      nan
      nan
```

However when I try to fill the nan with the values of another column:

```
 df['LC_REF'].fillna(df2['cycle'])
```

the nan values are not filled. Any clue as to what is going on?

```
df.head()

0    2C16                
1    3C16
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN   

df2.head()    
0  Elkjop,Generic,MSH,SBSO ME KSA
1  Elkjop,Generic,MSH,SBSO ME KSA
2                             DSG
```

Comment: What is `df2['cycle']`?

Comment: @willem the values from the other column

Comment: your `NaN` values look like strings... Is it an output of `print(df)`?

Comment: @MaxU Yes so I made the dataframe 6 rows, and filled the first 3 with the given information. I am now trying to fill the remaining nan with information from df2['cycle'] which happens to have 3 values.

Comment: @codeninja, your NaN's seem to be of a `str` dtype. You may want to check ScottBoston's solution...

Comment: @MaxU I did and unfortunately it is not giving me a correct output

Comment: @codeninja, can you post an output of `print(df.head())` and `print(df2.head())`?

Comment: I agree with @MaxU that we need to see both DataFrames.  When you pass a Series to `fillna` it aligns based on the index, so without seeing the index of both DataFrames it will be difficult to debug the issue.

Comment: Are df.LC_REF and df2.cycle the same length?  The must have different indexes that is why isn't working.

Comment: @ScottBoston, why did you delete your solution? I think it might be useful...

Comment: It wasn't working due to index alignment issues I suspect, the OP need to post more info about df and df2.  I felt it was a useless answer in this situation, I'll resubmit with more information.

Comment: i have edited the post to include the heads @MaxU

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget the `inplace` parameter

```
df['LC_REF'].fillna(df2['cycle'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately still not filling the nan values. I am at my wit's end! I've explored some past posts concerning nan not filling, but i have not found a solution

Comment: You can't fill a value with an entire column. Which particular value of df2.cycle goes into the `NA` values?

Comment: So my df2.cycle dataframe happens to be all the data that i need to fill the nan values which I guess is why it doesn't work. So my df2.cycle dataframe looks like 3C16 4C16 5C17. I wanted to fill the remaining nan values with those 3 elements

Comment: How do you decide which of the three elements goes into which NaN value?

Comment: @A.Kot I created a separate dataframe which is meant to populate those nan values

Comment: Right, but populate it with WHICH of the three elements. What happens when you have four NaN values?

Comment: @A.Kot It is meant to take the first 3 elements. Usually there will not be 4 elements.

Comment: If there is only three known values to fill with three missing value then `fillna` is not an appropriate function. Just update your values manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149746/discussion-between-codeninja-and-a-kot).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure those nan really are np.nan.

```
df['LC_REF'] = df['LC_REF'].replace('nan',np.nan).fillna(df2['cycle'])
```